# Angular 7 and IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, angular7, polyfills

I'm getting this error in IE 11 when viewing the angular app

```
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
zone.js (199,1)

if (this._zoneDelegate.handleError(this, error)) {
    throw error;
}
```

Using Angluar Core 7.2.15 and my polyfills I use

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
```

Not sure what else I could do

Comment: Those polyfills are only for the popular used es6+ functions which are not in IE11.
If your code contains more code that is not supported then you have to find the polyfill yourself. Ex. Object.entries we had to polyfill this ourselves even though we included the object from es6 import

Comment: Your polyfills should contain `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` which is the by default. I've tested my Angular 8 app in IE 11 and it works after adding ES6 polyfills. No problems with zone.

Comment: I thought `zone` import was done by default of the angular-cli. I didn't test this though

Comment: It is. But it's imported through polyfills. I got no idea why. Actually one can disable its import and Zones usage and start using manual change detection which would lighten the app weight and increase the total performance (in case of right change detection logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1804189/nico)'s suggestion was right. As he said core-js only provides polyfills for popular es6 features. I used `new URL()` which isn't supported by IE.

Comment: I did the same thing. I used `npm install url-polyfill --save` to install a polyfill for `URL`, and added it to the polyfill.ts file with `import 'url-polyfill';`

Answer (score 2):

You need to import all the polyfills required to make Angular app work in IE. Except the above polyfills you imported, please also uncomment the following polyfills in **polyfills.ts**:

```
import 'classlist.js';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Then you need to install some packages with npm:

```
npm install --save classlist.js
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

There's also [a blog](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9) you could refer to.